# Let's congratulate Connor Garcia on becoming our next moderator!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election, shoutout

## Congratulations!!!

Today, @ConnorGarcia was appointed as our next moderator!<sup>1</sup> So I just want to give a huge shoutout to him for having courage to self-nominate and take on a task that requires much time and effort. Hopefully we can get out of beta soon! **:)**

<sub><sup>1. I withdrew my nomination earlier, due to some minor issues.</sup></sub>